# Drawing line in reference of Geographic point (WGS84) using X,Y in meters and ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a CAD drawing (lines are circles) which I am trying to draw on an ArcGIS Map using JavaScript API.
I have a base reference Geographic point (WGS84) and North Angle in my source drawing, the rest of the drawing is in meters.

For example, I have reference WGS84 (Lat, Long, North angle) which is at X=20, Y=10 in CAD Drawing.
Now I have a line which is at (X1=25, Y1=25 to X2=30, Y2=30).

How I can draw that line in reference to that WGS84 point?

I am new to GIS.

Comment: You may want to leverage projection tools to convert that WGS84 reference point to the same projection as the CAD data. [link](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-projection.html)  Then you could programmatically plot the other points using plain math in the JS code.  I wonder though, are you just trying to do a one time dataset conversion?  Or is the use case to be able to repeat this process?  May be better to look into the ArcGIS Python API or ArcMap software if you have access. [link](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007831)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is not one time thing. We have to setup a process. The main thing which I want to understand is that I have a vector drawing (Created in CAD) e.g. a car in real world meters. When it was first drawn, it was not attached with any GIS reference system. Now is it possible to draw it in a GIS system using any metric projection (e.g. web Mercator)? I think I tried with Web Mercator EPSG:3857 but object looked bit smaller than the real world.